# Oscillating Output from Arduino Pins when not in use, why?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have A1 set to be an input, have the program read it, and then print to the serial monitor. My question is, when the circuit is not receiving power, but is grounded, and is still connected to A1, when do I see an output pattern of, for example:

```
0,0,0,0,7,23,16,9,4,0,0,0,0,3,18,21,15,0,0,0.....
```

I have a different detector inputing to A0 and if I don't have A1 connected then I get a reading that is similar to what I would see if I was actually reading A0 (around 900). Then if I plug back into A1 the value drops to around 350. When A0 is unplugged and only A1 is plugged in I only get noise (ie the pattern above in the code section).

Comment: Looks like the input pin is 'floating', picking up stray signals from the air. Do the numbers go higher as you move your hard closer, and decrease as you move farther?

Comment: looks like a sine wave to me, maybe AC coupling? Drawing current on the connected module could also pull up the ground, like seen on a shunt resistor.

Comment: @dandavis what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: @VE7JRO that's not exactly what I'm getting at, but thanks for the thought

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking along the same lines as CrossRoads and dandavis above. Would you be able to post a circuit diagram? If you haven't grounded the input, it could be floating or picking up noise from the surrounding environment. A 5k pulldown resistor may fix the problem, depending on what your circuit looks like and the environment its in.

Comment: ![Here is the link to my circuit diagram](https://crcit.net/c/50c1a524). Please for give me for any breach of standard practice, MechE by training haha

Comment: any thoughts @SirBagels?

Comment: @RyanB Without knowing more about what your'e trying to do with that circuit, it's hard to tell. The first thing I noticed was the 3M resistors, it seems pretty large. What caused you to pick that value? 5V/3M is approx 1.5uA. It doesn't take a ton of current to hit the high side of your Analog input. Try a few smaller values, 100k, 10k, etc. and see how that affects your results. I'd guess your're picking up noise from somewhere and the 3M resistor is kicking that into a readable voltage.